# How do I update my gui once it has been initialized with tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Why is screen.destroy() throwing an exception that screen is a null object? I am trying to update my screen label as the button is pressed, but it's not happening.

```
from tkinter import *

def buttonOne():
    num1.append("1")
    number = ""
    count = 0
    while count < len(num1):
        number = number + str(num1[count])
        count += 1
    screen1 = Label(text=number).grid(column=0, row=0)
    screen.destroy()

def main():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Calculator")
    global num1
    num1 = []
    global screen
    screen = Label(text="0.0").grid(column=0, row=0)    
    button1 = Button(text="1", command=buttonOne)
    button1.grid(column=0, row=2)
    window.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: fix the identation  problem in your code

Comment: I edited it to be more in form, and I just had the formatting wrong when I copied it to here.

Comment: explain what you want to achieve

Comment: Well I want screen to go away and screen1 to appear in it's place. Or alternatively, to update the text value of screen to "number" which is defined in buttonOne

Comment: better use `screen["text"] = number` to replace text in label.

Comment: screen["text"] = number is actually more what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem because you do

```
screen = Label(text="0.0").grid(column=0, row=0)
```

and it assings `None` to `screen` because `grid()` / `pack()` / `place()` returns `None`

You have to do it in two lines

```
screen = Label(text="0.0")
screen.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

---

BTW: you could replace text in label using one of method

```
 screen["text"] = "new text"
 screen.config(text="new text")
```

See

```
def buttonOne():

    num1.append("1")

    number = ""

    for item in num1:
        number += str(item)

    screen["text"] = number
```

Because you put only string on list then you can do it shorter

```
def button_one():

    num1.append("1")

    screen["text"] = ''.join(num1)
```

Full version

```
import tkinter as tk

def button_one():

    num1.append("1")

    screen["text"] = ''.join(num1)

def main():
    global num1
    global screen

    num1 = []

    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Calculator")

    screen = tk.Label(text="0.0")
    screen.grid(column=0, row=0)

    tk.Button(text="1", command=button_one).grid(column=0, row=2)

    window.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: I add more about `scree["text"] = "new text"`

Answer (score -1):

You having `Nonetype` error you have to place you grid on different line.

```
from tkinter import *

def buttonOne():
    global screen
    num1.append("1")
    number = ""
    count = 0
    while count < len(num1):
        number = number + str(num1[count])
        count += 1
    screen1 = Label(text=number).grid(column=0, row=0)
    screen.destroy()

def main():
    global screen
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Calculator")
    global num1
    num1 = []

    screen = Label(text="0.0")
    screen.grid(column=0, row=0)
    button1 = Button(text="1", command=buttonOne)
    button1.grid(column=0, row=2)
    window.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: and description/explanation ?

Comment: i was adding it bro

Comment: you could describe it much better - or show which part of code makes problem.